# Count Age With Distinctly in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this

```
PersonID  Gender Age CreatedDate
================================
1         M      32   10/09/2011
2         F      33   10/09/2011
2         F      33   10/11/2011
1         M      32   10/11/2011
3         F      33   10/11/2011
```

I want to find Gender Count By Age with group by created date,The age range will be 30-34 and getting person will be distinctly.

Desired output should like this:

```
Gender AgeRange CreatedDate  CountResult
================================
M      30_34   10/09/2011    1
F      30_34   10/09/2011    1
F      30_34   10/11/2011    1
```

So I tried this but couldtn help:

```
SELECT  t.Gender,'30_34' AS AgeRange,t.CreatedDate,
        SUM(CASE WHEN t.Age BETWEEN 30 AND 34 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CountResult,
FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT PersonID,Gender,Age,CreatedDate
FROM MyTable 
GROUP PersonID,Gender,Age,CreatedDate 
HAVING COUNT(PersonID)=1
) t
```

What can I do for solution?

Thanks

Comment: You store age? Are these individuals deceased?

Comment: Let's face it; this is a lousy example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are want the earliest created date per personid this might do
drop table if exists mytable;

```
create table mytable(PersonID int,  Gender varchar(1),Age int, CreatedDate date);
insert into mytable values 
(1 ,        'M',      32 , '2011-09-10'),
(2 ,        'F',      33 , '2011-09-10'),
(2 ,        'F',      33 , '2011-11-10'),
(1 ,        'M',      32 , '2011-11-10'),
(3 ,        'F',      33 , '2011-11-10');


select mt.gender,

        mt.createddate,
        sum(case when mt.age between 32 and 34 then 1 else 0 end) as Age32to34

from  mytable mt
where createddate = (select min(mt1.createddate) from mytable mt1 where mt1.personid = mt.personid)  
group by gender,mt.createddate
```

Answer (score 0):

You would appear to want:

```
SELECT t.Gender, '30_34' AS AgeRange, t.CreatedDate,
       COUNT(DISTINCT t.PersonId) AS CountResult
FROM MyTable
WHERE t.Age BETWEEN 30 AND 34
GROUP BY t.Gender, t.CreatedDate;
```

Comment: Where is from ?

Comment: Also I used sum using only one sql query cause of getting count of other age ranges 0_4,5_9,10_14 etc.

Comment: @kodcu . . . It is only possible to answer the question that you ask.  You should ask *another* question if you want more age ranges -- this one is pretty clear and already has answers.  If you change the question, you will likely invalidate answers which can draw downvotes.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
SELECT
    Gender
    , '30_34' AS AgeRange
    , CreatedDate
    , COUNT(*) AS CountResult
FROM MyTable A
JOIN (
    SELECT PersonID, MIN(CreatedDate) MinCreatedDate
    FROM MyTable GROUP BY PersonID
) B ON B.PersonID = A.PersonID AND B.MinCreatedDate = A.CreatedDate
WHERE Age BETWEEN 30 AND 34
GROUP BY Gender, CreatedDate
ORDER BY CreatedDate, Gender DESC
```